# How to debug Local Tile Update?

Tags: windows-phone-8, live-tile

I'm working on my app and i have added a tile update functionality but how to check for its working? Is there any way to check or debug it.

I'm using the below code for tile update

```
createTileData();
App.dayWordUpdate = new ShellTileSchedule(App.wordTile, App.tileData);
App.dayWordUpdate.Interval = UpdateInterval.EveryDay;
App.dayWordUpdate.Recurrence = UpdateRecurrence.Onetime;
App.dayWordUpdate.StartTime = DateTime.Now;
App.dayWordUpdate.Start();
App.isUpdateRunning = true;
```